# DataFrame calculating by group for log return of each stock

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As an example, I have created a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         date  price ticker  volume
0  2018-01-01  1.323     AI    2000
1  2018-01-02  1.525     AI    1500
2  2018-01-03  1.045     AI     500
3  2018-01-01  2.110    BOC    3201
4  2018-01-02  2.150    BOC    5200
5  2018-01-03  2.810    BOC    1980
6  2018-01-01  5.199    CAT    2000
7  2018-01-02  4.980    CAT     450
8  2018-01-03  4.990    CAT    3000
```

So there are 3 stocks and spanning over three days. I want to calculate the daily log returns for each stock between 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-03.

My current code is:

```
df["logret"] = df.groupby("ticker").apply(np.log(df.price) - np.log(df.price.shift(1)))
```

But it's throwing me an error message that the Series objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Can someone please explain to me what this error is pointing towards pls? And how to solve it to be able to compute the log returns by ticker names for each stock?

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, please consider accepting (green tick on left), so other users know.

Answer (score 8):

`np.log` then `groupby` with `diff`

```
df.assign(logret=np.log(df.price).groupby(df.ticker).diff())

         date  price ticker  volume    logret
0  2018-01-01  1.323     AI    2000       NaN
1  2018-01-02  1.525     AI    1500  0.142093
2  2018-01-03  1.045     AI     500 -0.377978
3  2018-01-01  2.110    BOC    3201       NaN
4  2018-01-02  2.150    BOC    5200  0.018780
5  2018-01-03  2.810    BOC    1980  0.267717
6  2018-01-01  5.199    CAT    2000       NaN
7  2018-01-02  4.980    CAT     450 -0.043036
8  2018-01-03  4.990    CAT    3000  0.002006
```

Answer (score 7):

I think need `lambda` function:

```
df["logret"] = df.groupby("ticker")['price'].apply(lambda x: np.log(x) - np.log(x.shift()))
print (df)
         date  price ticker  volume    logret
0  2018-01-01  1.323     AI    2000       NaN
1  2018-01-02  1.525     AI    1500  0.142093
2  2018-01-03  1.045     AI     500 -0.377978
3  2018-01-01  2.110    BOC    3201       NaN
4  2018-01-02  2.150    BOC    5200  0.018780
5  2018-01-03  2.810    BOC    1980  0.267717
6  2018-01-01  5.199    CAT    2000       NaN
7  2018-01-02  4.980    CAT     450 -0.043036
8  2018-01-03  4.990    CAT    3000  0.002006
```

Comment: I do not know either , Already upvote  this answer, So I will try to help with another one to get the your point back at least :-)

Comment: This answer is useful, I don't understand the downvote either.

Answer (score 5):

You can perform this calculation via a vectorised approach:

```
res = df.sort_values(['ticker', 'date'])

res.loc[res['ticker'] == res['ticker'].shift(), 'logret'] = \
np.log(df['price']) - np.log(df['price'].shift())
```

**Result**

```
         date  price ticker  volume    logret
0  2018-01-01  1.323     AI    2000       NaN
1  2018-01-02  1.525     AI    1500  0.142093
2  2018-01-03  1.045     AI     500 -0.377978
3  2018-01-01  2.110    BOC    3201       NaN
4  2018-01-02  2.150    BOC    5200  0.018780
5  2018-01-03  2.810    BOC    1980  0.267717
6  2018-01-01  5.199    CAT    2000       NaN
7  2018-01-02  4.980    CAT     450 -0.043036
8  2018-01-03  4.990    CAT    3000  0.002006
```

**Explanation**

- First sort your dataframe by `ticker` and `date`.
- Then apply your calculation when consecutive rows have the same `ticker`.
- Vectorising is more efficient than calculating results one at a time via `lambda`.

Comment: Thank you that's great. Can I ask if I have a predefined list, say top 3 stocks in the order of ["CAT","AI", "BOC"], how is it possible to create a res that sort_values the ticker column by the order for which the above predefined list is shown? Thanks

Comment: @cqstack, I suggest you ask a separate question so other users can benefit.

Answer (score 4):

I will do `pct_change` cause the log(a)-log(b)=log(a/b)

```
np.log(df.groupby('ticker').price.pct_change().add(1))
Out[729]: 
0         NaN
1    0.142093
2   -0.377978
3         NaN
4    0.018780
5    0.267717
6         NaN
7   -0.043036
8    0.002006
Name: price, dtype: float64
```